# How can I create a YouTube-like short domain redirection in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, youtube

*First, I would like to say what's a YouTube-like short domain redirection:*

If you go to: 
**youtu.be/jwslDn3ImM0**

It will redirect to: **www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwslDn3ImM0**

In my case. I two domains: **somethinghere.be** and **somethingheretube.com** and I want to do the same thing YouTube does.

How can I achieve this using the most efficient, fast, and secure way in .htaccess? Not that my .htaccess on the main domain **somethinghere.be** is still empty.

I know that I'm going to have to use:

```
RewriteCond
RewriteRule
```

But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: That is not how that works. Youtu (dot) be is a separate domain that forwards to the regular YouTube addresses.

Comment: Yes, true. I have a seperate (.be) domain, and it has an .htaccess file. I want to redirect it to my main domain.

Comment: In the htaccess file on your. Be domain, you would just have all requests forward to the regular domain. I. E.  `/([a-z0-9]+)$ http://otherdomain.com/watch=$1 ` I can't test the workability since I'm on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, in your `.htaccess` in root `tedtu.be` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ http://tedtube.com/watch?v=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you edit this answer so that it would redirect to *watch?v=* and not *watch=* I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: I change in my answer. It is necessary to clear the cache or try using a different browser (because R=301 use cache)